# Do Thorlabs piezoelectric transducers s PAZ009 and PAZ015 wor in vacuum?

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum, piezoelectric

We have few closed loop piezoelectric transducers (stacked) from Thorlabs, part numbers PAZ009 and PAZ015. I have prepared all the required feed through. I want to use them under rough vacuum $\sim 10^{-3}-10^{-2}\ \mathrm{mbar}$. I have asked Thorlabs about it but they have replied that these actuators are never tested under vacuum and they are not sure if they can work in vacuum.

Does anyone have experience working with them in vacuum, and know if they will work?

The Paschen curves for different gases shows that anything below $100\ \mathrm{V}$ is safe.
(from Krishnavedala [on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Paschen_curves.svg))

[image]

Comment: In general, yes, they'll probably work. Could you please give the part number? The question is too vague as written.

Comment: Typically in vacuum you need to worry about outgassing and heat removal. I doubt you'll have any problems.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the help, outgasing is no issue. I am concerned a bit about heat removal. PZT can be cooled effectively via translational stage. However the electronics may not be cooled that effectively. I am also worried about popping of capacitors in the vacuum.   One more concern is that the PZT is a stack, if this stack is made by gluing different crystals then they may get detached in vacuum.

Comment: The listed 75V drive voltage may be cause for concern, i.e. ionization and arcing with strong e-fields between close-spaced electrodes, especially across surfaces.  This is more of an issue above 10-2 mBar than below, and less issue if your chamber was flushed with air or N2 (Ar or He breaks down at lower volts.)  Perhaps ask Thorlabs if the driven electrodes on the pzt stack are covered in epoxy etc.

Comment: @wbeaty Thanks for your comment, it is actually useful. Please see the edited post and paschen curves and tell me if 75 V is concern or not

Comment: In general manufacturers are very conservative about the regimes in which they will state their product works. So if you ask whether something works under high vacuum or at millikelvin for example, you are unlikely to get a helpful reply unless the product is specifically designed for that purpose. That the manufacturer says the product has never been tested in vacuum is not _in itself_ a cause for concern.

Comment: @NLambert Thank you for your comment, It is really encouraging. I have opened the cover of the electronics and observed that two very small ICs are connected with the actuator hence it should be no problem. I will try it in coming 15 days and will post my observations. Regards

Comment: @DavidZ I can't answer because I haven't worked with the parts in question. If the question were of a more general type, e.g. asking if various electronics construction methods or materials were vacuum compatible I would be happy to answer.